# Find the integral of $\overline{z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, complex-numbers, self-learning

**Question:**
Find $\int\overline{z}$, when the contour is a parabola. Interval is from 0 to 1.

**My Attempt:**
$z = x + iy \Rightarrow \overline{z} = x - iy$
$f(z) = x - iy$

Since the contour is a parabola, $\gamma(t) = t + it^2$ and $y = x^2$.
$Re(\gamma) = t$, $Im(\gamma) = t^2$

$\gamma\prime(t) = 1 + 2ti$
$f(\gamma(t)) = (t - t^2)$

So, $\int_{c}\overline z = \int_{0}^{1}(t-it^2)(1+2t)$
$= \int_{0}^{1}(t - 2t^3) + i(2t^2 - t^2)$
$= (\frac{t^2 - t^4}{2}) + i(\frac{t^3}{3})$ *this must be evaluated from 0 to 1*
$= \frac{1}{3}i$

**Is my answer right?**

Comment: Chcek your work: that $1+2 t$ should be a $1+i 2 t$.

Comment: Do you want $\int \overline{z}\;dz$ ... or what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x,y)=x-iy$  and $\gamma(t):=x(t)+iy(t)=t+it^2$ with $t\in [0,1]$ then

$$f(\gamma(t)):=f(x(t),y(t))=x(t)-iy(t)=t-it^2$$

As $\gamma'(t)=1+2it$, we arrive at

$$\int_{\gamma} f:=\int_{0}^{1}f(\gamma(t))\gamma'(t)dt=\int_{0}^{1}(t-it^2)(1+2it)dt=
\int_{0}^{1}(t+2t^3)dt+i\int_{0}^{1}t^2dt=
\\ \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}i=
1+\frac{1}{3}i.$$

Comment: More problems like these please. Maybe I will try $z^2-4z$ from 0 $\to$ 1

Comment: It is better if you search for interesting examples by yourself and in case of issues/questions you post your computations on Math.SE

Comment: There are also *path-independent* integrals ?